# How can I handle two references to assemblies that have the same exports?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datacontractserializer

I just learnt about supporting roundtrip in serialization via DataContract. As I'm sure I will be making mistakes with this mechanism, I want to establish a unit test in Visual Studio to test whether the new versions of my files are ok.

In order to achieve this, I would like to

1. create a document object of the latest version in the unit test
2. Then serialize this object into a MemoryStream
3. Deserialize this object with an old version of my application
4. Serialize this old object to the MemoryStream
5. Deserialize this object with the current version
6. Check whether the properties of the first object and the last object are identical

This sounds simple (or maybe not?), my problem is now that the unit test needs a reference to the current version of my application and to an old version of my application at the same time.

So if I now try to create this object, I get an error saying that this type is defined in two assemblies.

So my question is, how can I handle two references to assemblies that have the same exports.

Can I do something like

```
OldAssembly.MyClass old;
CurrentAssembly.MyClass new;
```

Comment: Possibly, with each version, you could serialize your object(s) to a file or files (either XML for XmlSerializer or binary data for BinarySerializer) and you can then test deserializing these files to objects using the new versions of the classes? You only really need to serialize the old versions once then test deserializing them into the new version I suppose.

Comment: I recalled this really good question on a similar topic, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102614/is-there-any-point-unit-testing-serialization

Comment: You should change the title of this question to something similar to "how can I handle two references to assemblies that have the same exports."

Comment: @dash: no, I cant just use old files, because I want to check roundtrip. I want to set new properties in the current objects and be sure, if the old version loads and saves these objects, the new properties will still be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  > how can I handle two references to assemblies that have the same exports.
```

You can declare an [extern alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for every referenced assembly. This alias is usually `global` but you can declare your own either as commandline-argument for the compiler or in visual studio under ReferencedAssemlys/{MyAssemly}/Properties/Aliase.

In you Program you can use

```
old::My.NameSpace.MyClass old;
global::My.NameSpace.MyClass new;
```

Comment: I think this is the right track, but now I get "error CS1704: An assembly with the same simple name ... has already been imported".

Comment: To get rid of this error, I signed the two assemblies.
Now I get "warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict" and "error CS0432: Alias 'old' not found"

Comment: Resolved CS0432 by adding "extern alias old;". But I keep getting MSB3243 and MSB3247. And the test doesn't start because of System.IO.FileLoadException complaining about not finding the old assembly.

Comment: have both assemblies different file names? are the assemblies both copied to your exe-outputdir?

Comment: Yes they have different filenames, infact I renamed the old assembly in explorer. And no the old assambly is not copied to output, I don't know why. I copied this file manually to output.

Comment: I finally succeeded: I wrote an AssemblyResolveHandler that loads the old assembly when needed. I think the default resolver tried to load the new assembly and than complaint about not being the correct one. Now the only problems are the warnings MSB3243 and MSB3247 in UnitTestProject, but hey these are only warnings, just ignore it.